# This wall can be demolished, right?

Tags: walls, structural, load-bearing, demolition

Seems obvious to me that there is no load bearing on this wall since the wall stops at this point, but would love a second opinion.

[image: From one side]
[image: From the other]
[image: After removing sheetrock]

Comment: That appears to be the case (and that's as far as I'm willing to go from my chair in Notwhereyouareville).

Comment: Though your reasoning about the wall stopping isn't valid. Plenty of bearing walls terminate as such. We can't see from here what's above it all.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Single story house, nothing above

Comment: If you don't mind some mud work, knock out the drywall and look at the studs.  If the studs are just face nailed to the rafter, it is probably not structural.  If the rafter sits on a plates or a stud it might be but it might not.  If knocking out the wall is at all valuable to you, it is worth the few hundred to get an engineer to look at it.

Comment: I agree with isherwood. There will be electrical in the wall make sure to kill the power to those when doing the demo live lines can really ruin a blade and your day.

Comment: By design that wall is NOT load bearing, but that does not mean it is not bearing load.  In fact the opposite, if the center beam is insufficient it will actually hold up the center beam some via the cantilevered joist over the wall.  You SHOULD be safe to take the wall out, but consulting with some who knows how to verify (good general contractor or engineer) should be consulted.  Our house was critically supported by non bearing walls but we knew this upon purchasing and were able to safely resolve the issue because we knew the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've consulted with a local architect that thinks it can be removed. We took the sheetrock out this weekend to see what was inside, was surprised to see so many studs on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reason given (the wall stops - plenty of bearing walls do that) is not sound, but by cursory examination you appear to have a clearspan roof supported by beams that would have no reason to depend on this wall for support, so you are likely good to go. I'm guessing 1960's or early 1970's era based on the style (or when the style was popular in my area, anyway.)

As Ed notes, turn off the power first...

Answer (score 0):

This wall may not bear vertical dead loads, but it *could be* important in resisting shearing of the house in the direction perpendicular to the ceiling beams, e.g., in case of a high wind perpendicular to the direction of the beams. Get an engineer's report.

Comment: If it was a shear wall it would have been clad with plywood, not just sheetrock.